# How can I remove the Parallels icons from Launchpad in Lion?

Tags: macos, upgrade, parallels-desktop, launchpad

I have [Parallels Desktop 6](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) installed and after an upgrade to Lion I got a whole bunch of Windows app icons on Launchpad:

[image: Parallels icons on Launchpad]

They look ugly and don't have a remove button.
They also don't exist in my **Applications** folder so I can't delete them from there either.

How do I get rid of them?

Comment: I've stop any sharing between Mac and MS (except folders) after installing PD 7 (full screen mode)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue initially. After upgrading to the latest version of Parallels (which also solved the virtualization issue), all Windows applications were moved to `~/Applications (Parallels)` at the first start of Parallels and the icons now don't show up in Launchpad any longer.

Comment: So the upgrade solves the issue? Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I have PD 6 and all MS icons are only in this folder.

Answer (score 5):

The original [LaunchPad Cleaner](http://zoltanb.co.uk/launchpadcleaner/) would clean up the icons, but running parallels would undo the cleaning. The updated [LaunchPad Cleaner V2](http://zoltanb.co.uk/launchpadcleaner/) corrects that reversion and works to more permanently clean these parallels icons from the LaunchPad view.

Two other workarounds options are also available:

- [upgrade to the build that supports Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20029/unable-to-load-the-parallels-driver-after-upgrade-to-lion/20031#20031), as [suggested](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20024/how-to-remove-parallels-icons-from-launchpad-in-lion/20034#20034) by patrix (free for v6 users);
- disable Windows application integration by right-clicking Parallels icon in Dock, selecting **Configure...** for the running machine and unchecking **Share Windows applications with Mac** in **Applications** section:

  [image: Disabling Windows application integration]

  Of course this will also make these shortcuts unavailable on Mac.

Comment: You can only disable sharing windows applications with Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I had Windows XP installed using Parallels.
I got rid of the Parallels trial as I bought VMWare instead.

In order to clean up my LaunchPad I found that I had to find the following directory: "Windows XP Applications" and delete it.

To find where the directory was I typed into spotlight "internet explorer" without the quotation marks.
NOTE: To open the containing folder of "internet explorer" I held down the Command key and click on "internet explorer".

I then dragged the folder "Windows XP Applications" that was containing "internet explorer" to the Trash Bin.

Then I opened a terminal session and typed the following:
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db
sudo killall Dock

That cleaned up my LaunchPad.

Note it took about 10 to 15 seconds to for LaunchPad reindex the correct applications.

Doug

Answer (score 0):

Launchpad-Control is what you're searching for
http://chaosspace.de/dev/launchpad-control-hide-apps-from-launchpad/

Comment: Thanks, I [have just found it myself](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20024/how-to-remove-parallels-icons-from-launchpad-in-lion/20026#20026). Welcome to AskDifferent!

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works the first time but then the icons get restored.

Answer (score 0):

To delete for ever, simply go to `Finder` -> `Applications` -> `My Bootcamp Applications`.

Remove all links in there, and Launchpad will automatically remove them.

Normally, the links will still come back if you do a refresh reset, but this method should work.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to remove those annoying icons.

Download Launchpad Cleaner2. since it's a tryout it lets you only delete the first page and the default icons, like Safari.
So what I did was gathered all the Parallels icons into 3 folders and name them Safari2, then Launchpad Cleaner took it as default and I was able to delete them.

Answer (score -1):

In your Application directory, there's a folder for virtual machine windows programs (it's hidden, or somehow not easily accesible). You can do a global search for the program name ("internet explorer" i.e), and go to the containing folder. Finally, remove the folder entirely.

Comment: I didn't find any hidden folder in /Applications, do you remember the name?

Comment: i think it's something like "windows xx application". But you just need to do a search in Finder with the win app name, you should see the shortcut in the result list, then right click it and choose "open enclosing folder".