# "Unable to load the Parallels driver" after upgrade to Lion

Tags: macos, upgrade, virtualization, parallels-desktop

I have [Parallels Desktop 6](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) (**6.0.11994**) installed and after an upgrade to Lion, whenever I start Parallels, I get these two messages:

[image: Your virtual machine may run slow because virtualization is disabled on your Mac]

[image: Unable to load the Parallels driver. Restart your Mac and try again.]

Then **Parallels Virtual Machines** window appears but neither of them can be started.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the Lion compatible version of Parallels installed! The current version is 6.0.12094.

[image: Parallels About Screen]

You can download the latest version from [Parallel's download page](http://www.parallels.com/download/desktop/) or use **Check for Updates...** in **Parallels Desktop** menu.

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions to this problem.

The easiest, and permanent solution is to **upgrade the Parallels to the latest build**.
**The upgrade is free for existing version 6 users.**
The official [KB article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/111463) says:

> Parallels Desktop 6 for Mac (build **12094 and higher**) is compatible with Lion.

To upgrade, [go to the download page](http://www.parallels.com/download/desktop/) or click **Check for Updates...** in **Parallels Desktop** menu:

[image: Check for Updates...]

If you don't yet want to upgrade, you can use a workaround below:

1. Launch **AppleScript Editor** (it's in **Utilities** folder)
2. Create a new file (**File > New**)
3. Copy and paste this into the editor:

   > do shell script "for x in prl_hypervisor prl_hid_hook prl_usb_connect prl_netbridge prl_vnic; do
   >   sudo kextutil -q \"/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/Kexts/10.6/$x.kext\"
   >   done" with administrator privileges
   >   do shell script "open -a \"/Applications/Parallels Desktop.app\""
4. Select **File > Save**, call it **Parallels Desktop Launcher**, put it in the **Applications** folder and set type to **Application**:

[image: Parallels Desktop 6 Lion workaround]

The new launcher will appear in your **Applications** folder and you will be able to use it **to start Parallels**. You will need to enter your password once before the start because the script needs administrative privileges.

[image: Parallels Desktop 6 Lion launcher]

Note that there are also **other problems** with Lion incompatibility in versions prior to 6.0.12094 and this only fixes startup. I also had a problem with Parallels virtual machine window being only briefly visible during Spaces transition, as if it were above all windows in the system. Apparently, I had **Coherence** mode set by default, and there seem to issues with it on the older versions. I fixed the problem by clicking the red Parallels icon in the menu bar and choosing **Exit Coherence**:

[image: Exit Coherence]

To fix the same issue with Parallels configuration window not appearing, I had to change **Assign to** from **None** to **All Desktops**.

[image: Parallels configuration window is invisible fix]

Comment: One question pops into my mind: why would one go this extremely complicated way over installing a free update that solves the issue? Is it the download size?

Comment: @mwidmann: I edited the answer to reflect that the upgrade is free for the existing v6 users. Personally, I use 3G via my cell operator for the internet connection and I already exceeded the 2GB traffic limit so a temporary workaround helps a huge.

Comment: Some people around do not want to register, and you can't get updates if you don't register.
For me the procedure above solved the problem.
Many thanks!